# Excel: Scalar product of two ranges

Tags: excel, formula, scalar

I am trying to find a proper way to calculate the scalar product of two ranges. For instance, the product of `A1:A3` and `B1:B3` would be `A1*B1 + A2*B2 + A3*B3`. Is there a good way to do this? Hardcoding this calculation is quite a tedious thing to do with large ranges.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use this one

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3,B1:B3)
```

Comment: Note that if one array is in a row and the other is in a column you need to use =SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3, TRANSPOSE(B1:B3))
 and then press Crtl+Shift+Enter to confirm.

Answer (score 13):

**SUMPRODUCT formula – syntax and usage**

Excel SUMPRODUCT formula - tutorialThe sum-product formula syntax is very simple. It takes 1 or more arrays of numbers and gets the sum of products of corresponding numbers.

```
The syntax is =SUMPRODUCT (list 1, list 2 ...)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Update on 11/30/2022

Considering the [Excel Spill feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531), now you can use `SUM` for most of the cases `SUMPRODUCT` was used, for example:

```
=SUM(A1:A3*B1:B3)
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample output]